# Update rows in mysql via id

Tags: php

Ok i have this code.

```
<? //process.php, this will be use in updating, adding, deleting items and content
$a = $_POST['hid'];
$b = $_POST['doctitle'];
$c = $_POST['doccontent'];

if (isset($_POST['hid']) && ($_POST['doctitle']) && ($_POST['doccontent']))
{

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE doc SET title='$b', content='$c' WHERE id='$a'");

echo "<h2>Successfully updated.</h2>";

mysql_close($con);

}
else
{
echo "not been set, failed to process. please try again.";
}
?>
```

I want to update the specified row on the table doc, it should update the title in this $b and the content in this $C via id $a. but nothing happen, is there wrong in my code?, nxt is I want to know if the record has been update. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error (e.g. by calling `mysql_error`)?

Comment: And, by the way, you should sanitize your inputs to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

1. If `id` is an integer column you shouldn't use `'` around it's value:

   `WHERE id=$a`
2. You can check number of affected rows using [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function:

   `$rowsAffected = mysql_affected_rows($con);`
3. You should also check the query string and try to execute it on MySQL manually (on PhpMyAdmin, or something similar), to check if it works fine then.
4. Your code has no anti-SqlInjection parts. You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or any kind of escape function to make it more secure.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the if statement is firing (ie is $_POST['hid'] and the other post vars set)? Also, why do you run isset() on 'hid' and not the other 2 vars?

Oh, and as stated above, you should always sanitize your vars to protect against MySQL injection. You can always use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Actually, `if($_POST['doctitle'])` is almost the same as `if(isset($_POST['doctitle']) AND !empty($_POST['doctitle']))`.

Comment: True, but why do it for 1 and not the others? It's just inconsistent.